# how to do a smooth scroll down a page with javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function scrollWin() {
    setInterval(function(){ for(var i = 0; i < 1250; i++){
    window.scrollTo(0, i);} }, 3);
  
  }
```

```css
li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
.reset {
  clear: both;
}
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
  <li><button onclick="scrollWin()"></a>about</button>
  
  <li><a href="#"></a>profile</li>
  <li><a href="#"></a>contact</li>
</ul>
<div class="reset"></div>
<section>
  <div id="home1"></div>
  <div id="about1">About</div>
  <div id="profile1"></div>
  <div id="contact"></div>
</section>
```

so im trying to make the for loop increase the height by 1 each loop which will make the screen drop by the height of one.  Using a time interval for a very short amount of time I would believe this would make a smooth scroll down the page.

Comment: we're gonna need more.

Comment: Indeed I don't think you know what you're askin here. JQuery already has a scroll method and jQuery Easing makes it even more interesting. Try those before making your own.

Comment: I don't think you understand the nature of asynchronous programming in JavaScript. Please see my answer below and read more on JavaScript here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a sample code in php where scroll bar appears if the loop run for second time as in the question you asked I hope.
 so define a variable first and then increase it in your loop as follows:

```
<?php
$i=1;
for(condition;condition;condition){
     //your code here
     $i++;
}

if($i<1){
 echo '<script>
         $(".yourdivclass").css("overflow","scroll");
       </script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit of JavaScript should perform nicely what you are asking. I have a fiddle that I have set up as a usage example. Please check it out and let me know if you have any questions.

https://jsfiddle.net/6gp7srfr/1/

```
function smoothScroll(x, y) {
    var b = document.body;
    var xIncrement = 1;
    var yIncrement = 1;
    var scrollY = function () {
        yIncrement += 1;
        window.scroll(b.scrollLeft, b.scrollTop + yIncrement);
        if (b.scrollTop < y) {
            if (requestAnimationFrame) {
                requestAnimationFrame(scrollY);
            } else {
                setTimeout(scrollY, 15);
            }
        }
    };
    var scrollX = function () {
        xIncrement += 1;
        window.scroll(b.scrollLeft + xIncrement, b.scrollTop);
        if (b.scrollLeft < x) {
            if (requestAnimationFrame) {
                requestAnimationFrame(scrollX);
            } else {
                setTimeout(scrollX, 15);
            }
        }
    };
    if (y > 0) {
        scrollY();
    }
    if (x > 0) {
        scrollX();
    }
}
```